# OpenCL kernels arguments ambiguity

Tags: opencl

I have two functions:

```
void sum1(short * a, short * b, short * res, int size);
void sum2(float * a, float * b, float * res, int size);
```

and I have a single generic kernel

```
__kernel void sum(__global const T * a, __global const T * b, __global T * res, int size)
{
int x = get_global_id(0);
if (x < size) res[x] = a[x] + b[x];
}
```

is it safely to invoke this generic kernel from functions presented above with compile options -D T=short and -D T=float respectively? Do I need to use alignment or does OpenCL automatically align kernel arguments in this case to 2 and 4 bytes respectively?

In general, when I am passing cl_mem object to a kernel OpenCL does not know about a data type that stored in this cl_mem object and I could understand how OpenCL "transforms" cl_mem object to appropriate pointer in kernel arg.. I need help with that

Answer (score 0):

1- Yes. It is safe to use directly `-D T=short` or float at compile time. Since it will generate 2 proper kernels.

2- OpenCL (and other programming languages with pointers) understand that the pointer you are passing has a type. And they stick to this type when addressing the memory.
At least in C, this is not a problem since automatic pointer casting is not allowed. And the programmer gets an error if the pointer doesn't match.

However in OpenCL, the memory zones of a buffer are considered generic or void pointers. When you assign them to a kernel, the cast is implicit in the assignment. But this doesn't mean it is correct !

For example. If you create a float buffer, fill it with floats, use it as an argument to short kernel. The result will be wrong, since the kernel will interpret the buffer wrong. However if you do it wrong by passing a short array to a float kernel, the result will be a SEG_FAULT.

Comment: thanks, but what's about alignment? Does a programmer need to align kernel arguments? or do such cases exist when we need to use alignment?

Comment: You don't need to align any array or struct, as long as you don't hack the access to the elements like `*(((char *)pointer)+1)`. However some structures may work better if aligned. BTW, there is no aligment at all if you simply use array of single elements.